# How to display data in Dictionary in custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `AFNetworking 3.0`.

In View controller I have displayed multiple Speciality title in each cell. After tap on particular cell, I got response from server like following:

```
[{"dp":{"id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":0,"specialization1":"Orthopaedics","specialization2":"Dermatologist","specialization3":"Neurology","url":"www.batras.com"},"ds":{"city":"agiripalle","consultation_fee":450,"contact_no":"1234567890","country":"India","id":18,"organization_name":"Batra","pin_code":"411052","reg_id":0,"state":"andhra pradesh","street_name":"jhbfahjf","wellness_flag":false},"reg":{"mobile_no":0,"name":"Batra","profile_id":0,"reg_id":157,"wellness_id":"251215782521"}},{"dp":{"id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":0,"specialization1":"Orthopaedics","specialization2":"Dermatologist","specialization3":"Neurology","url":"www.batras.com"},"ds":{"city":"anur","consultation_fee":458,"contact_no":"1234567898","country":"India","id":19,"organization_name":"Danny","pin_code":"411052","reg_id":0,"state":"himachal pradesh","street_name":"afafwfw","wellness_flag":false},"reg":{"mobile_no":0,"name":"Batra","profile_id":0,"reg_id":157,"wellness_id":"251215782521"}},{"dp":{"id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":0,"specialization1":"Orthopaedics","specialization2":"Dermatologist","specialization3":"Neurology","url":"www.batras.com"},"ds":{"city":"pabal","consultation_fee":500,"contact_no":"4512451252","country":"India","id":20,"organization_name":"Org Name","pin_code":"411052","reg_id":0,"state":"maharashtra","street_name":"afawafww","wellness_flag":false},"reg":{"mobile_no":0,"name":"Batra","profile_id":0,"reg_id":157,"wellness_id":"251215782521"}},{"dp":{"id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":0,"specialization1":"Orthopaedics","specialization2":"Dermatologist","specialization3":"Neurology","specialization4":"Gynecologist","url":"danny.com"},"ds":{"city":"bumlitan","consultation_fee":504,"contact_no":"1234567898","country":"India","id":21,"organization_name":"Danny","pin_code":"411052","reg_id":0,"state":"andaman and nicobar islands","street_name":"East Street","wellness_flag":false},"reg":{"mobile_no":0,"name":"Danny","profile_id":0,"reg_id":167,"wellness_id":"311220165848"}},{"dp":{"id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":0,"specialization1":"Orthopaedics","specialization2":"Dermatologist","specialization3":"Neurology","specialization4":"Gynecologist","url":"danny.com"},"ds":{"city":"amtala","consultation_fee":451,"contact_no":"1234567898","country":"India","id":22,"organization_name":"Danny","pin_code":"411052","reg_id":0,"state":"assam","street_name":"West","wellness_flag":false},"reg":{"mobile_no":0,"name":"Danny","profile_id":0,"reg_id":167,"wellness_id":"311220165848"}},{"dp":{"id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":0,"specialization1":"Orthopaedics","specialization2":"Dermatologist","specialization3":"Neurology","specialization4":"Gynecologist","url":"danny.com"},"ds":{"city":"hala","consultation_fee":541,"contact_no":"1234567890","country":"India","id":23,"organization_name":"Danny Clinic","pin_code":"411123","reg_id":0,"state":"chandigarh","street_name":"Chandigarh","wellness_flag":false},"reg":{"mobile_no":0,"name":"Danny","profile_id":0,"reg_id":167,"wellness_id":"311220165848"}}]
```

After that I handle that response like following way:

```
NSLog(@"Response from specialization server  :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: kNilOptions error: nil];
if (ResponseArray.count >0)
{
    _spclarr = [ResponseArray mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"special_array : %@",_spclarr);
    _spclstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_spclarr];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // saving an NSString
    [prefs setObject:_spclstr forKey:@"spcl"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"doctorspcl" sender:self];
}
[self getdata:responseObject];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
          {
     // If Error occure, then this is AlertController Appear
                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

In next view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *s = [prefs stringForKey:@"spcl"];
    NSLog(@"spcl: %@",s);
    menuItems=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"menu: %@",menuItems);
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menuItems count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Doctordetail";
            DoctorDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"content: %@",content);
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
            NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Cell Clicked: %@",menuItems);
    NSLog(@"content2: %@",content);
    }
```

When I run app on simulator, it works. when I click on particular cell, the log prints data of that cell.

here is menuItems:

```
menu: (
    "(\n        {\n        dp =         {\n            id = 0;\n            qualification = \"MD(Doctor)\";\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;\n            specialization2 = Dermatologist;\n            specialization3 = Neurology;\n            url = \"www.batras.com\";\n        };\n        ds =         {\n            city = agiripalle;\n            \"consultation_fee\" = 450;\n            \"contact_no\" = 1234567890;\n            country = India;\n            id = 18;\n            \"organization_name\" = Batra;\n            \"pin_code\" = 411052;\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            state = \"andhra pradesh\";\n            \"street_name\" = jhbfahjf;\n            \"wellness_flag\" = 0;\n        };\n        reg =         {\n            \"mobile_no\" = 0;\n            name = Batra;\n            \"profile_id\" = 0;\n            \"reg_id\" = 157;\n            \"wellness_id\" = 251215782521;\n        };\n    }",
    "\n        {\n        dp =         {\n            id = 0;\n            qualification = \"MD(Doctor)\";\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;\n            specialization2 = Dermatologist;\n            specialization3 = Neurology;\n            url = \"www.batras.com\";\n        };\n        ds =         {\n            city = anur;\n            \"consultation_fee\" = 458;\n            \"contact_no\" = 1234567898;\n            country = India;\n            id = 19;\n            \"organization_name\" = Danny;\n            \"pin_code\" = 411052;\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            state = \"himachal pradesh\";\n            \"street_name\" = afafwfw;\n            \"wellness_flag\" = 0;\n        };\n        reg =         {\n            \"mobile_no\" = 0;\n            name = Batra;\n            \"profile_id\" = 0;\n            \"reg_id\" = 157;\n            \"wellness_id\" = 251215782521;\n        };\n    }",
    "\n        {\n        dp =         {\n            id = 0;\n            qualification = \"MD(Doctor)\";\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;\n            specialization2 = Dermatologist;\n            specialization3 = Neurology;\n            url = \"www.batras.com\";\n        };\n        ds =         {\n            city = pabal;\n            \"consultation_fee\" = 500;\n            \"contact_no\" = 4512451252;\n            country = India;\n            id = 20;\n            \"organization_name\" = \"Org Name\";\n            \"pin_code\" = 411052;\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            state = maharashtra;\n            \"street_name\" = afawafww;\n            \"wellness_flag\" = 0;\n        };\n        reg =         {\n            \"mobile_no\" = 0;\n            name = Batra;\n            \"profile_id\" = 0;\n            \"reg_id\" = 157;\n            \"wellness_id\" = 251215782521;\n        };\n    }",
    "\n        {\n        dp =         {\n            id = 0;\n            qualification = \"MD(Doctor)\";\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;\n            specialization2 = Dermatologist;\n            specialization3 = Neurology;\n            specialization4 = Gynecologist;\n            url = \"danny.com\";\n        };\n        ds =         {\n            city = bumlitan;\n            \"consultation_fee\" = 504;\n            \"contact_no\" = 1234567898;\n            country = India;\n            id = 21;\n            \"organization_name\" = Danny;\n            \"pin_code\" = 411052;\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            state = \"andaman and nicobar islands\";\n            \"street_name\" = \"East Street\";\n            \"wellness_flag\" = 0;\n        };\n        reg =         {\n            \"mobile_no\" = 0;\n            name = Danny;\n            \"profile_id\" = 0;\n            \"reg_id\" = 167;\n            \"wellness_id\" = 311220165848;\n        };\n    }",
    "\n        {\n        dp =         {\n            id = 0;\n            qualification = \"MD(Doctor)\";\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;\n            specialization2 = Dermatologist;\n            specialization3 = Neurology;\n            specialization4 = Gynecologist;\n            url = \"danny.com\";\n        };\n        ds =         {\n            city = amtala;\n            \"consultation_fee\" = 451;\n            \"contact_no\" = 1234567898;\n            country = India;\n            id = 22;\n            \"organization_name\" = Danny;\n            \"pin_code\" = 411052;\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            state = assam;\n            \"street_name\" = West;\n            \"wellness_flag\" = 0;\n        };\n        reg =         {\n            \"mobile_no\" = 0;\n            name = Danny;\n            \"profile_id\" = 0;\n            \"reg_id\" = 167;\n            \"wellness_id\" = 311220165848;\n        };\n    }",
    "\n        {\n        dp =         {\n            id = 0;\n            qualification = \"MD(Doctor)\";\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;\n            specialization2 = Dermatologist;\n            specialization3 = Neurology;\n            specialization4 = Gynecologist;\n            url = \"danny.com\";\n        };\n        ds =         {\n            city = hala;\n            \"consultation_fee\" = 541;\n            \"contact_no\" = 1234567890;\n            country = India;\n            id = 23;\n            \"organization_name\" = \"Danny Clinic\";\n            \"pin_code\" = 411123;\n            \"reg_id\" = 0;\n            state = chandigarh;\n            \"street_name\" = Chandigarh;\n            \"wellness_flag\" = 0;\n        };\n        reg =         {\n            \"mobile_no\" = 0;\n            name = Danny;\n            \"profile_id\" = 0;\n            \"reg_id\" = 167;\n            \"wellness_id\" = 311220165848;\n        };\n    }\n)"
)
```

and content:

```
content: (
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            url = "www.batras.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = agiripalle;
            "consultation_fee" = 450;
            "contact_no" = 1234567890;
            country = India;
            id = 18;
            "organization_name" = Batra;
            "pin_code" = 411052;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = "andhra pradesh";
            "street_name" = jhbfahjf;
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 157;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
    }
2016-12-21 13:52:48.184 Wellness_24x7[1223:55790] content: 
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            url = "www.batras.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = anur;
            "consultation_fee" = 458;
            "contact_no" = 1234567898;
            country = India;
            id = 19;
            "organization_name" = Danny;
            "pin_code" = 411052;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = "himachal pradesh";
            "street_name" = afafwfw;
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 157;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
    }
2016-12-21 13:52:48.185 Wellness_24x7[1223:55790] content: 
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            url = "www.batras.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = pabal;
            "consultation_fee" = 500;
            "contact_no" = 4512451252;
            country = India;
            id = 20;
            "organization_name" = "Org Name";
            "pin_code" = 411052;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = maharashtra;
            "street_name" = afawafww;
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 157;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
    }
2016-12-21 13:52:48.187 Wellness_24x7[1223:55790] content: 
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            specialization4 = Gynecologist;
            url = "danny.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = bumlitan;
            "consultation_fee" = 504;
            "contact_no" = 1234567898;
            country = India;
            id = 21;
            "organization_name" = Danny;
            "pin_code" = 411052;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = "andaman and nicobar islands";
            "street_name" = "East Street";
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Danny;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 167;
            "wellness_id" = 311220165848;
        };
    }
2016-12-21 13:52:52.862 Wellness_24x7[1223:55790] content: 
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            specialization4 = Gynecologist;
            url = "danny.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = amtala;
            "consultation_fee" = 451;
            "contact_no" = 1234567898;
            country = India;
            id = 22;
            "organization_name" = Danny;
            "pin_code" = 411052;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = assam;
            "street_name" = West;
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Danny;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 167;
            "wellness_id" = 311220165848;
        };
    }
2016-12-21 13:52:52.962 Wellness_24x7[1223:55790] content: 
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            specialization4 = Gynecologist;
            url = "danny.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = hala;
            "consultation_fee" = 541;
            "contact_no" = 1234567890;
            country = India;
            id = 23;
            "organization_name" = "Danny Clinic";
            "pin_code" = 411123;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = chandigarh;
            "street_name" = Chandigarh;
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Danny;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 167;
            "wellness_id" = 311220165848;
        };
    }
)
2016-12-21 13:52:53.918 Wellness_24x7[1223:55790] content: (
        {
        dp =         {
            id = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 0;
            specialization1 = Orthopaedics;
            specialization2 = Dermatologist;
            specialization3 = Neurology;
            url = "www.batras.com";
        };
        ds =         {
            city = agiripalle;
            "consultation_fee" = 450;
            "contact_no" = 1234567890;
            country = India;
            id = 18;
            "organization_name" = Batra;
            "pin_code" = 411052;
            "reg_id" = 0;
            state = "andhra pradesh";
            "street_name" = jhbfahjf;
            "wellness_flag" = 0;
        };
        reg =         {
            "mobile_no" = 0;
            name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 157;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
    }
```

but **my problem is**, it doesn't display in `UITableViewCell`

I tried to display it like following way:

```
[cell.drname setText:[[content objectForKey:@"dp"]valueForKey:@"qualification"]];
```

as well as
 `[cell.drname setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[content objectForKey:@"dp"]valueForKey:@"qualification"]]];`

but it gives me error like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a07c600'

I didn't get that, where I am wrong.

Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

Comment: First check `NSString *str = [[content objectForKey:@"dp"]valueForKey:@"qualification"];`. Does it crash?

Comment: @nynohu yes, it crash with same error..

Comment: use [[content objectForKey:@"dp"]objectForKey:@"qualification"];

Comment: I tried that @DipankarDas .. same error:(

Comment: NSLog(@"menu: %@",menuItems); output ?

Comment: can you output the value of content

Comment: ( { dp = {id = 0; qualification = "MD(Doctor)"; "reg_id" = 0;specialization1 = Orthopaedics;specialization2 = Dermatologist;specialization3 = Neurology; url = "www.batras.com";}; ds ={city = agiripalle;"consultation_fee" = 450;"contact_no" = 1234567890;country = India;id = 18; "organization_name" = Batra;"pin_code" = 411052;"reg_id" = 0;state = "andhra pradesh";"street_name" = jhbfahjf;"wellness_flag" = 0;};reg =  { "mobile_no" = 0;
name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            "reg_id" = 157;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
    } ......@Joshua

Comment: The error means that you are trying to get `objectForKey:` in `NSString` - this means that you have to check that data is converted to `NSDictionary` - thats all.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper menuItems are correct, in tableview menuItems.count  is right... just how to display it? is my question

Comment: Do next to get where is mistake of type `NSDictionary * dp = [content objectForKey:@"dp"];` then `NSDictionary * qualification = [dp valueForKey:@"qualification"];` some of this data is wrong type

Comment: After  NSDictionary * dp = [content objectForKey:@"dp"];  log doesn't print, it crash @Nazir

Comment: @ Suraj Sukale you have a NSArray not NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make following changes.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"YourURL" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    NSArray *ResponseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
    if (ResponseArray.count >0)
    {
        _spclarr = [ResponseArray mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"special_array : %@",_spclarr);

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        // saving Array to NSUserDefaults
        [prefs setObject:_spclarr forKey:@"spcl"];
        [prefs synchronize];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"doctorspcl" sender:self];

    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

In detail View Controller

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //directly reading the array
    menuItems = [prefs objectForKey:@"spcl"];

}
```

your cellForRowAtIndexPath should look like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *menuItems = [prefs objectForKey:@"spcl"];
    NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[[content objectForKey:@"dp"]valueForKey:@"qualification"]];
    return cell;


}
```

When we get the response in array format then why are you storing it in `NSUserDefaults` as NSString ? To get rid of it you need to store an Array directly in `NSUserDefaults` and use that array directly.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ba7fe00'.. @Mahesh

Comment: @SurajSukale did you made the changes as i suggested ?

Comment: @SurajSukale comment the line `[cell.textLabel setText:..` in `cellForRow..` method and check again.

Comment: @SurajSukale i call API and show data in same ViewController and it's working fine for me. [see my complete code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23663200/)

Comment: -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b000600
got this when i commened [cell.textLabel setText:.. in cellForRow.. method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131140/discussion-between-mahesh-and-suraj-sukale).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have a `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`. try this-

```
NSArray* arr = @[@{@"dp":@{@"id":@"0",@"qualification":@"MD(Doctor)"}},
                           @{@"ds":@{@"id":@"1",@"qualification":@"MD(Nurse)"}}];

NSDictionary *dpDict = [[arr objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"dp"];
NSString *str = [dpDict valueForKey:@"qualification"];
```

here, you get the string. It doesn't crash.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use

`NSString *str = [[[menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"dp"]valueForKey:@"qualification"];`
 to get the string.

Comment: yes, i get string, but how i do that, because here dict is predefined ? ... @Dipankar

Comment: Can u show NSLog(@"content: %@",content); from cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @SurajSukale you can get your response inside array.

Comment: result of NSLog(@"content: %@",content); updated in my que.. @DipankarDas

Comment: use this, after content in cellForRowAtIndexPath -  NSLog(@"%@",[[content objectForKey:@"dp"] valueForKey:@"qualification"]); to check the string.

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b000600   @DipankarDas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131141/discussion-between-dipankar-das-and-suraj-sukale).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dpDict = [content objectForKey:@"dp"];
    if (dpDict && [dpDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && [dpDict objectForKey:@"qualification"] != nil) {
    [cell.drname setText:[dpDict objectForKey:@"qualification"]];
}
```

Comment: -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a045400 ...@nynohu

Comment: Updated answer. Could you check the dpDict type and show for me?

Comment: same error ...@nynohu .. when i print dpDict, it crash

Comment: Could you show me     `NSLog(@"menu: %@",menuItems);` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: please check my updated question. i mention menuItems in that..@nynohu